# Why pclose() return 32512 (exit code 127) when system() succeeds on identical command?

Tags: macos, cgi, popen

I'm calling:

```
FILE *fp = popen(cmd,"r");
...
fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",pclose(fp));
```

I am calling this from a CGI script.

This used to work, but recently the command being run has started to mysteriously fail, so I added the fprintf to see what status code pclose() is returning, and I was surprised to see it is 32512, which corresponds to an exit code os 127.  I have verified that the command is not actually being run, and the return value corresponds to exit status 127.

I tried running `otool -L` on the binary being run, and everything looks fine.  I am invoking the command with the full path to the command, so there is no change it isn't finding the executable.  I have printed the current directory to make sure I'm where I think I am, and have verified that the binary is visible.

If I run the exact same command logged in as the same user as the CGI runs as it works fine.  If I run the exact same command by passing it to `system()` it works there also!  It only fails when I try to run it via `popen()`.

What the command is doesn't even seem to matter! I replaced it with other commands such as `ls` and I still get this weird exit code.

I am running out of things to try.  What else could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody runs into this issue in the future, here is how I resolved it.  There was a previous call to `popen()` in the code and a review of the code showed that it was mistakenly closed with `fclose()` instead of `pclose()`.  Because the previous popen call was closed improperly, it prevented future invocations from working properly.

Answer (score 0):

On my case I was running different shells on the terminal(zsh) and on the C command execution shell(bash).

The command I was running was an alias set in the default terminal shell and wasn't showing up in the C commands execution shell.

All I did was to now add the alias to `.bashrc` and that fixed the error.

Confirm the respective active shells with command `echo $0`